# modify wordpress custom field value - strip character if exists

Tags: custom-field

Does anyoone know if its possible to check a custom field value for a character such as a currency symbol and then remove it from the field value so that the field contains a numerical value, not an alphanumercial / text value ?

If so, what would be the best approach for this ?

The field auto updates so it would need to be some kind of regular conditional test and modification - is there a way to attach the test to trigger when the field updated ?

Maybe this would require some kind of field mapping ?

Comment: Just thought about it and something like this, mapping the value into a new field would do it I think;

<?php
global $post;
$pricewithsymbol = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'THEORIGINALFIELD', true );

if (strpos($pricewithsymbol, '$') !== false) {
$pricewithoutsymbol = preg_replace("$", "", $pricewithsymbol); 
}

update_post_meta($post_id, 'THENEWFIELD', $pricewithoutsymbol);
?>

Comment: How would I que this so that it only ran when viewing or editing post pages ?

Comment: This is more a PHP/JavaScript question than a WordPress one.

Comment: @Wyck, that actually depends on where he is using this. Where are you using this? You trying to filter this out of the edit page? Or on display?

Answer (score 2):

You might try this:

```
<?php
$str = 'This is a very large number 999,999,999.999 !';
echo $str = preg_replace( '/[^\d,.]/', '', $str );
```

to only allow:

- digits (0-9)
- commas (,)
- dots (.)

You might then consider filters like:

```
add_{$meta_type}_metadata
update_{$meta_type}_metadata
get_{$meta_type}_metadata
```

where  `$meta_type` is the type of object metadata (comment, post or user).

**ps:** just remember to take backup before testing these filters ;-)